# Pyinstaller : Link .exe files

Tags: python, pyinstaller

In my project I have used two python scripts.

1. main.py
2. imports.py

Imports.py contain all the library imports, such as panda, numpy etc.
I have imported imports.py in main.py to access the numpy and pandas.My aim is to keep all the imports in one file.After building main.py, Pyinstaller added all dependencies In main.exe itself.
I want to isolate dependencies and code so that I only need to build main.py if any code change occure.I expect two independent exe files 1) main.exe 2)imports.exe and main.exe could add all dependencies in imports.exe on runtime. What is the proper method?

Comment: As far as I understand your description you access other libraries in `main.py` with e.g. `import imports.numpy`. Is that correct? But it seems you don't understand how tools like Pyinstaller work. They bundle your scripts, the libraries and the full Python interpreter in one file. If you have two of those generated executables they will be fully independent, so there is no sharing of code.

Comment: You have a misunderstanding of how executable files work.  When you run your web browser, are there multiple exe files you need to activate in order to make it work?  Or how about a media player?  No there is usually just one executable file